# Java Applet Audio Crackling/Clicking when Multiple Files Playing

Tags: java, performance, audio, applet

Quite simply, whenever I play my audio in my Applet (it triggers on collisions, which there are many of) if one starts in the middle of another of the same type it will 'pop' (crackle, click, distort etc.)

```
AudioClip audio[] = new AudioClip[10];
int i = 0; //IMPORTANT! Do not reset at any time during runtime

public void loadSound(String sound){
    File file = new File(sound);
    try {
        audio[i] = Applet.newAudioClip(file.toURL());
        i++;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void playSound(int pos){
    audio[pos].play();
}
```

I call this with the playSound method, and sure enough the sounds play exactly as you would expect. But with my second file in the list, a pop occurs if it is played during the playback of another.
I do not reload my audio files each time, I only set them to play.

I imagine there's a vastly better way to do this, but all the documentation I can find is circa 2002. How does everyone else do it?

Comment: "`//IMPORTANT! Do not reset at any time during runtime`" Wouldn't it just be easier to use a list?